# Dual booting from Windows 7 hard disk and a VHD file

Tags: windows-7, vhd

I have Windows 7 Enterprise edition installed on my laptop on the real physical hard disk. Now I want to create a vhd partition on the c:\ root directory and be able to dual boot into my real machine or a vhd that also runs Windows 7.
Is this possible at all and if, yes how. If I try to do it, the installation on the VHD says that it is going to rename some operating system files that it found on the C:\ drive.

Comment: Should move this over to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this [article](http://edge.technet.com/Media/Windows-7-Boot-from-VHD/).  It seems to provide some good directions for what you need to do.